# How to use variables in sed on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, sed

I'm writing a batch script to automate build events on Windows, and as part of it I need to change some lines in a few files. So I'm going to use sed. But how do I use variables in sed inside a batch script?

Comment: How are you going to use a unix utility on Windows?  What version of Windows are you using.  We need more specifics.

Comment: That would be another question. I'm using Win7, but I've been told I have to use sed for the modification of the files.

Comment: And there are versions of sed for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`, **No**.  Might it be easier to use `sed`, **Yes**.  Just want to make sure you understand that you are not limited to just `sed`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe

Comment: I'm told I have to use sed. I'm aware there are other ways to solve the problem, but those are the *constraints I have been given*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the variables using the usual `%varname%` syntax used by `cmd.exe`.  As shown in this example, I've defined two variables `old` and `new` and substituted them into a `sed` expression on the command line.  Typing `original` into the input, `sed` echos back `new and improved`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

c:\Users\Nicole>set old=original

c:\Users\Nicole>set new=new and improved

c:\Users\Nicole>sed "s/%old%/%new%/"
original
new and improved
^Z
```

Comment: what is %new% contains backslashes? E.g., `set new=c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` ? Sed wants to escape the characters and you end up with `c:indowsystem32md.exe`

Comment: @pbarney Escape the `\ ` escape character. This is part of the sed syntax. Write it as `set new=c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thanks that helps, but what if you don't know the value? For example, if you're doing a character replacement on an environment variable with contains backslashes?

Comment: @pbarney If you're using a Unix shell on Windows that supports command substitution, you could use sed to replace all the \'s with two \'s, e.g., `set escapenew = \`echo $new | sed "s/\\/\\\\/g"\``